# How do I write a script to count the total number of files, and directories in my home directory then display it?

Tags: shell, shell-script, directory, home

I want to do it with a `for` loop. This is what I've come up with so far which does not work.

```
for home in /home/ {.,/}*; do echo "$home"; done
```

I would like to do this non-recursively if possible.

Comment: Interesting question.  My first thought is that it's not possible, but I'm not sure.  If it is possible it's a lot more difficult non-recursively.  So much more difficult that for any tree structure traversal, recursion is the only way I can remember seeing it done.

Comment: Well I suppose a recursive method would work too. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Since it changed, I'm editing your Title and Question a little.

Comment: How about `find ~ | wc-l` ?

Comment: Trying to make it work with a for loop somehow.

Comment: Please don't. Using the shell for this is much harder than it needs to be, very fragile and easy to get wrong, and orders of magnitude slower than using `find`.

Comment: @terdon I infer that this questioner wants to do this as a learning exercise,   not asking for the best way to do it.  Questioner specified `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many higher level commands that will almost do what you want to do, but this is a good demonstration of how to do the same thing in a shell script.  This should work on *any* system that has `/bin/sh`.  It's not dependent on any other commands.

You can save this script as any filename, and then type `sh ./whatever_you_named_it` to execute it.

I've split this into two sections, **Listing the Files**, and **Counting the Files**.  Listing the files recursively is the most complicated, but once we have a list, it's easy to count them.

**Listing the Files**

This script recursively lists all of the files and directories under your home directory or a directory it receives as a parameter.  With no parameters, it defaults to the home directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

if test $# -eq 0
then
    startdir="$HOME"
else
    startdir="$1"
fi

for f in "$start"/*          # step through all files in the starting directory
do
     echo "$f"               # print the file name
     if test -d "$f"         # is the file a directory? (-d)
     then
        sh "$0" "$f"         # yes call this script with the dir as arg
     fi
done
```

Let's discuss each step:

1. If no parameters were passed to the script, then use "$HOME" as the starting directory, otherwise use the first parameter. ($# contains the number of parameters passed to this script and we use the shell's built-in `test` command to find out if it's zero):

   ```
   if test $# -eq 0
   then
           startdir="$HOME"
   else
           startdir="$1"
   fi
   ```
2. Iterate over files in your home directory.  `"$HOME"/*` expands to all of the non-hidden files and directories at the top level of your home directory:

   ```
   for f in "$HOME"/*
   do
   ```
3. Print the file name.  I think you know `echo`:

   ```
        echo "$f"               # print the file name
   ```
4. Call the shell built-in `test` command with the `-d` option. `test` returns true if the argument, `"$f"`, is a directory. This is most often written as `[ -d "$f" ]` for brevity, but it really is a command. [Search for "test expr" in the `sh` man page]:

   ```
       if test -d "$f"         # is the file a directory? (-d)
       then
   ```
5. This next statement is where we recur. We start a new copy of the currently running script and pass a the current "$f" directory name to it. The `$0` expands to the filename of the current shell script. Rather than type some filename here, we use `$0` so this script will work even if it's name is changed. For example, if the script was called `rlist`, then you could also write `sh rlist "$f"`, but if the script was renamed, the script would no longer function correctly, because it would be calling a non-existent script, or the wrong script. [See "Special Parameters" in the `sh` man page]:

   ```
           sh "$0" "$f"         # yes call this script with the dir as arg
   ```
6. Terminates the `if` statement and the `for` loop.

   ```
        fi
   done
   ```

**Counting the Files**

The script so far lists the files but does not count them.  If you want to get a count of all the files and directories execute this:

```
sh ./scriptname | wc -l
```

`wc -l` is the "word count" command, and with the `-l` option counts only the lines.  The above pipeline prints a number which is the number of files under your home directory.

Comment: you should `exec` at least, but it would be better to use a function. as is you need a shell process - and a separate PID - per child directory. it also branches into infinite loops fairly easily with a few nasty symlink placements - which would make it a fork bomb.

Comment: @mikeserv All true, but way beyond the level of understanding of the questioner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31348/discussion-between-robertl-and-mikeserv).

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks!  I can respond to that!   Current version is tested.  Thanks for bringing it down to my level! :--)

Comment: @David-Prentice I just edited this to fix a serious problem.  Please note the addition of the `if` statement at the top of the script.  This is critical to keep the script from looping for ever.

Comment: the `for f in "${1:-$HOME}"/*` would behave identically to your current edit, if it matters. also `startdir=~` and `startdir=$HOME` are interchangeable statements. the `test $#` is possibly subject to splitting on  an environment `$IFS` value if any. *(try `ln -s "$(command -v bash)" sh; IFS=0 PATH=.:$PATH command sh yourscript` and `ln -sf "$(command -v dash)" sh;IFS=0 PATH=.:$PATH command sh yourscript` to see how `bash` and `dash` behave differently when called as `sh` regarding an exported `$IFS` value. both behaviors are perfectly valid by spec)*

Comment: Doesn't list/count files and directories beginning with dot; see http://superuser.com/questions/373746/how-to-use-one-shell-globbing-expression-to-list-all-files-of-course-hidden-f .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks.  I allude to this in the annotation #2: "all of the _non-hidden_ files and directories"

Comment: @mikeserv `${1:-default}` is how I prefer to do it, but I chose to keep syntax as simple as possible with minimum of features/syntax needed to understand the script.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

with `find` for not directory types in the current directory without recursing:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -type d | grep -c /
```

...for only directories drop the second bang, or for all filetypes drop the `-type` test entirely.

that's easy in this case because without recursion we only ever see one path delimiter per file and so there is no confusion about what and where to count. counting newlines when you should be counting files can lead to trouble - the two things are unrelated. so what to do otherwise?

```
find .//. | grep -c '^\.//\.'
```

...will return an accurate count of child objects + this object rooted in the current directory.

equally as valid, but with reversed logic because it quotes newlines internally and probably faster because it needs only to `stat()` each directory rather than every constituent file:

```
\ls -1qRA . | grep -Exc \[^/]+
```

if you drop the `-R` option to `ls` it will work without recursion just as well.

it is possible, though, that the above could return a false count depending on multibyte characters in filenames and incompatible locale settings. putting `LC_ALL=C` in a POSIX-conformant `ls`'s environment would protect against that, and for depth counts of a sizable tree, doing so can only help matters with regards to performance after all.

Answer (score 0):

Use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

When you say non-recursively, did you mean that you only want a count of files/directories in /home, but not any subdirectories?  If that is the case, you can restrict results to the top level with the `maxdepth` option.

```
find /home -maxdepth 1 | wc -l
```

Using for:

```
i=0; for home in ~/*; do (( i++ )); done; echo $i
```

Note the spaces between the double parentheses and the enclosed i++.

Comment: Note that your `find` breaks for file/dir names containing newlines and the `for` breaks for just about everything, including simple spaces. In any case, this is recursive and the OP asked for a non-recursive solution.

Comment: @terdon a bit harsh don't you think?  The OP asked for a non-recursive solution and `maxdepth` would prevent recursion into subdirectories.  The OP *never* mentioned filenames containing whitespace or newlines.  Sure, that can be handled with quoting and `-print0`, respectively, but I simply wasn't giving him more than he asked for.

Comment: Oh, good grief, sorry! I completely missed the `-maxdepth` option. Could you at least edit it into all of your suggestions? The `for` loop is still recursive. My main gripe though is i) this will break on strange filenames and ii) the `for item in $(find)` is very, very bad practice. At least use a shell glob `for item in /home/*` There's no point in using `find` if you specifically don't want recursion, that's just making it more complex and more fragile since it can't deal with whitespace correctly. The OP's original version deals with whitespace just fine.

Comment: are you jim morrison? @terdon - the home thing is not recursive. oh. the `(find ~)` thing was in a previous version, yeah. the `for` loop is silly in any case: `set -- ~/*; echo "$#"` would behave identically and without the fuss. it doesnt handle dotfiles though - except `.` itself and only in the case of an empty directory. whats `-maxdepth` all about, anyway? ive never understood what it does, except that its supposed to go in a special arg position. i mean, does it offer anything that a simple `-prune` doesnt?